# Multiple FM radio streams from /dev/radio* via v4l2, ices2 and icecast

Tags: streaming, v4l

I have an FM radio USB dongle (Silicon chip),  I have managed to stream the radio reception via icecast using the following configuration:

- the USB dongle is recognized by v4l2 driver and mounted at /dev/radio0 as a separate audio device
- Pulseaudio uses the FM radio device as a record device
- ices2 uses the 'alsa' module with 'pulse' as device
- ices2 connects and streams to an icecast server.

This is fine, but if there is a second FM radio USB dongle mounted at /dev/radio1, I would like to have a second stream at the same time. Is there any possibility that ices2 can receive audio data directly from /dev/radio0 and /dev/radio1 separately and stream different channels?

Would there be any other solution, like the Pulseaudio serve different recording input to each software source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The answer was easy. As you can see in the picture, PulseAudio allows different capture inputs for each recording software (in our case for each ices2 Alsa capture module).

[image: PulseAudio configuration for streaming two different USB Dongles]

Therefore, one needs to start ices2 twice with one separate configuration file each

Each ices2 should define a new alse pulse source:

```
    <input>
        <module>alsa</module>
        <param name="device">pulse</param>
        <!-- Read metadata (from stdin by default, or -->
        <!-- filename defined below (if the latter, only on SIGUSR1) -->
        <param name="metadata">1</param>
        <param name="metadatafilename">test</param>
    </input>
```

And two different instances

E.g for the first ices2

```
<instance>
        <!--    Server details.

            You define hostname and port for the server here, along
            with the source password and mountpoint.  -->

        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
        <port>4888</port>
        <username>source</username>
        <password>pasword</password>
        <mount>/radio1.ogg</mount>

</instance>
```

for the second ices2

```
<instance>
        <!--    Server details.

            You define hostname and port for the server here, along
            with the source password and mountpoint.  -->

        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
        <port>4888</port>
        <username>source</username>
        <password>pasword</password>
        <mount>/radio2.ogg</mount>


</instance>
```